# Passing parameters dynamically with HREF

Tags: jsp, dynamic, parameters, href

could anyone tell me if it is possible to pass parameters dynamically with HREF?

PageOne of jsp:

```
<%
while(rs.next())
{

%>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="coursedetails.jsp? value = <%= rs.getString(1)%>" > <%= rs.getString(1)%>      
       </a></td>
    <td name = <%= rs.getString(2) %> >  <%= rs.getString(2) %></td>
    <td> <%=  rs.getString(3) %> </td>
</tr>

<%   
 }
%>
```

PageTwo of jsp

```
// the following code does not seem right. 
String value = request.getParameter("value");
String name = request.getParameter("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the blank spaces. Try this

```
<a href="coursedetails.jsp?value=<%= rs.getString(1)%>"><%= rs.getString(1)%></a>
```

Also there isn't any parameter named "name" in the URL. so `request.getParameter("name")` will always return null. To add a second parameter, you will have to add the "&" symbol as below

```
<a href="coursedetails.jsp?value=<%= rs.getString(1)%>&name=<%= rs.getString(something)%>"><%= rs.getString(1)%></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its old post. I identify some Error.You dont pass name attribute.

```
<%
while(rs.next())
{

%>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="coursedetails.jsp?value="<%=rs.getString(1)%> "&name="<%=rs.getString(2)%> >      
       </a></td>
    <td name = <%=rs.getString(2)%> >  <%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
    <td> <%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
</tr>

<%   
 }
%>
```